# Modulo Time do Python com erro no Idle

Tags: python, time, clock

[image: Erro]

O Idle está apresentando este erro, e não consigo achar uma forma de corrigi-lo, parece que ele não importou o módulo time ou não está reconhecendo.

Se alguém puder me orientar.

Answer (score 0):

Eu vi que você está usando python 3.8 e **time.clock** foi descontinuada então tente usar **time.process_time()** no seu caso seria **t.process_time()**.

Uma dica: ficaria muito mais fácil se eu pudesse rodar o seu código pra testar as mudanças tornaria minha resposta mais eficaz sem eu ter q digitar um código novo então smp q possível mande o código que não funciona na pergunta. :)